# find and assign a string to a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

How to find a string from a file using bash.

I got a file "version.txt" and the file has the content

```
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
```

Need a bash command to extract the value of version key dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

```
version=$(grep ^version version.txt | cut -d'"' -f2)
```

Answer (score 0):

awk -F '='  '{print $2}'  version.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of one of the following commands and assign the result to a variable:

**INPUT:**

```
$ cat version.txt 
abc
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
123
```

**grep:**

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=^version\s=\s")[^"]*' version.txt                                                                                
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**perl:**

```
$ perl -ne 'if(/^version/){s/^version\s*=\s*|"//g; print}' version.txt                                                           
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

There are many other ways of reaching your result (`sed`,`awk`,...)

**Explanations:**

1) You use `grep` in `perl` mode and use lookbehind assertion, in this case I have supposed that your equal is always surrounded by 1 and only 1 space

2) The `perl` approach is more flexible (0,1 or more spaces can be located around the equal character), here the principle is that you identify the line starting with `version`, then you remove the `version =` and double quotes before printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(awk '/version/ {print $3}' file.txt)
```

/EXPR/ <- You can use a regex like expression with awk.
$3 since we are interested in the third column, you could also use this code:

```
var=$(awk '/version/ {print $(NF)}' file.txt)
```

NF in awk is the number of fields of the current line, in this case 3.